# Setting RAW values in GDB

Tags: gdb

I'm trying to set float register values in GDB.  `set $f` works in most cases but not in cases where NAN or INF is used.  Is there a way to set the actual RAW bytes in the register?

For example:

```
(gdb) set $f31 = 4.4
(gdb) info reg $f31
f31            4.4000000000000004       (raw 0x401199999999999a)
```

I want to be able to directly manipulate the  raw bytes to a NAN or INF.

edit:

Thanks to user @ssbassa!  I'm stil not used to stack overflow so I don't know how to mark that as a solution but they recommended doing this:

`set $f31=1./0` for INF and `set $f31=0./0` for NAN.

That being said: I'd like to also know how to set these values:

SOLUTION: use `set (void*)`

```
(gdb) set (void *) $f1 = 0x1
(gdb) info reg $f1
f1 4.9406564584124654e-324 (raw 0x0000000000000001)
```

```
double precision +/- pynan  0x(7)FFFC_0000_0000_0000
single precision +/- pynan  0x(7)FFC0_0000
double precision +/- qnan   0x(7)FFFC_0000_0000_0001
double precision +/- snan   0x(7)FFF8_0000_0000_0001
double precision +/- inf    0x(7)FFF0_0000_0000_0000
single precicion +/- qnan   0x(7)FFC0_0001
single precicion +/- snan   0x(7)FF80_0001
double precision +/- inf    0x(7)FF80_0000
double precicion neg zero   0x8000_0000_0000_0000
single precision neg zero   0x8000_0000
```

Any idea on these ones?

Comment: How about `set $f31=1./0` for INF and `set $f31=0./0` for NAN.

Comment: Thank you for this!  I've updated the question.  idk how to mark your answer as a solution...  But there are a few more values I need to know how to set

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user @ssbassa’s comment:

Set `$f31=1./0` for `INF` and set `$f31=0./0` for `NAN`.

That being said: I'd like to also know how to set these values. The solution to that is to use `set (void*)`:

```
(gdb) set (void *) $f1 = 0x1
(gdb) info reg $f1
f1 4.9406564584124654e-324 (raw 0x0000000000000001)
```

Comment: You can only mark answers as accepted, not comments. Since @ssbassa left the answer as a comment, you’re doing the right thing by “elevating” it to an answer. (Alternatively, you can also leave a comment giving them the option to do so.)